# Error :4:1 multiplexer

Tags: verilog

I am getting compiling error while on 2'b100 as it says that `Bounds of part-select into 'mux_out' are reversed`. Is this the right way to do ?

```
  /* 4:1  MUX */

   always@(gs_latch[47:0] or gs_latch[95:48] or gs_latch[143:96] or gs_latch[191:144] or xlat_cnt[1:0])

     begin
    case(xlat_cnt[2:0])
      3'b001 : mux_out[47:0] = gs_latch[47:0];
      3'b010 : mux_out[95:48]= gs_latch[95:48];
      3'b011 : mux_out[143:96]= gs_latch[143:96];
      3'b100 : mux_out[144:191] = gs_latch[144:191];
      default : mux_out = 47'bx
    endcase // case (xlat_cnt[1:0])
     end
```

Comment: What are you compiling?

Answer (score 2):

Your `mux_out` bus is only 48 bits wide, right? (You didn't show this.) Therefore, the left-hand sides of your assignments have the wrong bit indices, which could actually be eliminated altogether:

```
/* 4:1  MUX */

always @(gs_latch, xlat_cnt) begin
  case (xlat_cnt[2:0])
    3'b001 : mux_out = gs_latch[47:0];
    3'b010 : mux_out = gs_latch[95:48];
    3'b011 : mux_out = gs_latch[143:96];
    3'b100 : mux_out = gs_latch[191:144];
    default : mux_out = 47'bx
  endcase
end
```

Actually, your original problem is simply that you said `144:191` instead of `191:144` for that particular case.